# Шахматное преобразование таблицы на SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, преобразование

Добрый день! Есть таблица:

```
|event|id |timestamp|
---------------------
event1|001|21-03-15 |
event2|001|22-03-15 |
event1|002|23-03-15 |
event2|002|24-03-15 |
```

Какой должен быть запрос, чтобы вывести результат:

```
id |event1  |event2  |
----------------------
001|21-03-15|22-03-15|
002|23-03-15|24-03-15|
```

Помогите, пожайлуста, уже вторую неделю не могу сделать :)
Ясно одно, что сначала надо делать выборку уникальных id:

```
SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id;
```

А дальше как то так:

```
SELECT timestamp WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id) AND event='event1';
```

event заранее известны(event1,event2)
Если есть повторяющиеся события под одним id,с разным или одинаковым timestamp, добавлять колонки в результат, например:

```
id |event1  |event2  |event1  |event2  |
----------------------------------------
001|21-03-15|22-03-15|23-03-15|23-03-15|
002|23-03-15|24-03-15|NULL    |NULL    |
```

Comment: А что должно происходить, если для id 001 есть несколько событий одного типа с разными timestamp

Comment: в идеале - добавлять новые колонки в результат

Comment: Я дал предварительный ответ, но задача с динамическим добавлением колонок на SQL не разрешима

Comment: Вы текущий ответ посмотрите, может пригодится и потом я его удалю, потому как под вашу текущую постановку задачи он не годится и задача при такой постановке на SQL не разрешима, только на клиенте собирать

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, а насчет динамического добавления столбцов я думаю надо так: записать результат в другую таблицу; сделать еще один запрос и дописать повторяющиеся event

Comment: Дописать куда ? Просто в SQL динамическое кол-во колонок в принципе невозможно. Хотя может для этого в каких то СУБД и придумали какие то хитрые средства, но я их не знаю. Кстати, можно в mysql в одну колонку вывести значения через запятую например, но там ограничение на 255 символов в такой строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем виде так:

```
SELECT A.id,GROUP_CONCAT(B.timestamp) AS event1,GROUP_CONCAT(C.timestamp) AS event2
  FROM (select distinct id from test) A
       LEFT JOIN test B ON B.id=A.id and B.event='event1'
       LEFT JOIN test C ON C.id=A.id and C.event='event2'
 GROUP BY A.id
```

НО, в данном виде функция соберет таймстампы повторяющихся событий для конкретного id в строку, через запятую. Если timestamp не строки, то из надо явно преобразовать к строке при передаче в `group_concat`. По умолчанию максимальная длина строки формируемой group_concat - 1024 байта.

Comment: а как добавить еще один столбец, только не timestamp, а comment?(он ТОЛЬКО напротив event1)

Comment: Наверно `B.comment` или group_concat от него. Или я вас не так понял

Comment: SELECT A.id,B.timestamp AS event1,C.timestamp AS event2,D.comment as comment
  FROM (select distinct id from test) A
       LEFT JOIN test B ON B.id=A.id and B.event='event1'
       LEFT JOIN test C ON C.id=A.id and C.event='event2'
       LEFT JOIN test D ON D.id=A.id and D.event='event1'
так не работает.. много повторяющихся значений с id

Comment: А зачем `D` еще клеить в запрос, если он полностью идентичен `B`. используйте B.comment

Comment: Добавился столбец в первой таблице, - comment(он не null только где event='event1'), и соответственно в результирующей таблице тоже добавится столбец comment, который будет брать значение из test.event='event1'

Comment: Ну так когда event='event1' - это у вас в запросе таблица B - вот и берите из нее.

Comment: Спасибо! Пиво с меня.